# Is there a mistake in wikipedia article on interior?

Tags: general-topology

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) wikipedia article about the interior, in the section on the interior operator, it is written that $S^{\circ}=X\setminus(X\setminus\bar{S})$, which can't be true since $X\setminus(X\setminus\bar{S})=\bar{S}$.

I think a correct definition would be $S^{\circ}=X\setminus(\overline{X\setminus{S}})$. Am I right?

Comment: Hey @Whyka i think you are right^^ $X \setminus \tilde{S}$ is open, it's complement closed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right and Wikipedia is wrong.

Comment: So much for the myth of Wikipedian Infallibility.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the wikipedia page.

Comment: @bof: I’ve not encountered that myth; the common myth is that Wikipedia is reliably *wrong*, which is just as silly. (In my experience the mathematics and linguistics articles are generally pretty decent. This mistake looks to me like either a typo or a slip of the mind.)